# Getters/setters of a class having a map

Tags: java, interface, encapsulation, getter-setter

What is the best practice in implementing/providing getters/setters for a class containing a map?

The most common implementation I see is:

```
public class MyClass {

  private Map<String, String> myMap;
  public getMyMap() { /* Return an unmodifiable map */ }
  public setMyMap(Map<String, String> myMap) { ... }
}
```

Or would it be better to provide an interface like:

```
public getMyMap() { /* Return a modifiable map */ }
public addToMap(String key, String value) { myMap.put(key, value); }
```

And why is such method better?

Comment: I would always try to use the second option where possible, but where you've got to expose javabean getters/setters you sometimes have no choice.

Comment: Depends solely on whatever the map represents (thus, the functional requirements). This is usually to be documented on the class and/or the methods. There is no real answer to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both have their uses. **The methods exposed by a class should be of a proper level of abstraction.** For example if the class is a registry of dogs backed by a `Map<String, Dog>`, then it could provide methods like:

```
void addDog(String name, Dog dog);
Dog findByName(String name);
```

If it's say a rule engine that allows clients to specify the entire rule set in one call, then it could expose methods like:

```
void setRules(Map<String, Rule> rules);
Map<String, Rule> getRules();
```

Answer (score 4):

In general I would say try not to return the map at all.  Have a method that takes the key and returns the value.  Taking a map is ok, as long as you copy it, but a method that takes the key/value and puts it into the map would be my preference.

If you must return the map you should return a read-only version or a copy of it.  A set method should also copy the map.

It is a bad idea to allow callers to mutate the data inside of a class without the class knowing, passing or holding onto mutable data is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on your requirement. This may suffice in most of the cases.
You may not even have a getter method that returns the map. If you use my plug-in, it may help you creating those methods : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/documentation.htm#create-list-map as eclipse will not help you create the add method.

Answer (score -5):

I would just provide one.  Something like...

```
public Map<String,String> getMyMap()
{
   return myMap;
}
```

and when you want to use it then

```
myClass.getMyMap().put(key,value);
```

DISCLAIMER: I did not compile this and test this answer ;)